# Using mobile phone's internet through bluetooth

Tags: networking, internet, bluetooth

How can I connect to a mobile phone through a bluetooth connection to use the mobile phone's internet connection?

Comment: i recommend to create a wifi hotspot on in your phone and accesss the internet